# Mocking a Dateformat (SimpleDateFormat) in JUnit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, simpledateformat

Im trying to test a DAO function which uses a DateFormat (SimpleDateFormat). When I try to run the test im getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
```

This points to : election.setStartDate(df.format(rs.getDate("startDate"))); in the DAO

This it the test code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdminDaoImplTest {

    @Mock
    Connection mockConn;
    @Mock
    PreparedStatement mockPreparedStmnt;
    @Mock
    ResultSet mockResultSet;

    @Mock
    DateFormat formatter;

    @InjectMocks
    private AdminDao adminDao = new AdminDaoImpl();

    @Mock
    private SQLConnection mockSqlConnection;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void init() throws SQLException {
        when(mockSqlConnection.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConn);
        when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);
        when(mockPreparedStmnt.executeQuery()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
        when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
when(formatter.format(any())).thenReturn("'2018-11-12 00:00'");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetElectionsNoExceptions() throws SQLException {

        ElectionListResponse electionListResponse = new ElectionListResponse();

        adminDao.getElections('>' );

        //verify and assert
        verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString());
        verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).executeQuery();
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).next();
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getInt("id");
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("name");
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getDate("startDate");
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getDate("endDate");
    }
}
```

This is the function in the DAO:

```
@Override
    public ElectionListResponse getElections(char selector) {
        ElectionListResponse electionListResponse = new ElectionListResponse();

        String query = NamedQueries.GET_ELECTIONS_BEGIN + selector + NamedQueries.GET_ELECTIONS_END;

        try {
            con = sqlConnection.getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

            while (rs.next()) {
                Election election = new Election();
                election.setElectionID(rs.getInt("id"));
                election.setElectionName(rs.getString("name"));
                election.setStartDate(df.format(rs.getDate("startDate")));
                election.setEndDate(df.format(rs.getDate("endDate")));
                electionListResponse.addElection(election);
            }
            return electionListResponse;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cant get elections. ", e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have tried some examples i've found online, but I'm still getting the same error. I also have read that DateFormat is a final function and cannot be mocked. There where some workarounds, but didn't work for me. I'm not sure I've implemented those workaround correctly.

Could you please provide me the code to fix this NullPointer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're mocking DateFormat then why you're creating SimpleDateFormat object?

Comment: I was trying some different kind of solutions online. I will edit that one out.

Comment: could it be that your rs.getDate("startDate") returns null?

Comment: Yes! Thats right.

Comment: Mocking `SimpleDateFormat` is probably a bit overdoing it. Why not use the real thing.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't see anything mocking rs.getDate() so that is going to return null. That will probably cause problems with both mocked and real instances of `SimpleDateFormat`. You can address that like this:

```
// (I am using the deprecated constructor for simplicity)
java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(2018, 6, 5);
Mockito.when(mockResultSet.getDate("startDate")).thenReturn(startDate);
```

That combined `when(formatter.format(any())).thenReturn("'2018-11-12 00:00'")` *might* get you past the exception. It looks, though, like you are creating a real `SimpleDateFormat` inside `AdminDaoImpl` and your mocked one wouldn't get used at all. So you will have to either modify `AdminDaoImpl` to allow you to inject the `SimpleDateFormat` or write your tests so that they do not know that `AdminDaoImpl` uses `SimpleDateFormat`.

Personally, I wouldn't mock the SimpleDateFormat at all. Instead, I would treat it as an internal implementation detail of `AdminDaoImpl`. I would mock the result set to return the date and then verify that the `ElectionListResponse` has the expected date. That would look something like this:

```
// (I am using the deprecated constructor for simplicity)
java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(2018, 6, 5);
Mockito.when(mockResultSet.getDate("startDate")).thenReturn(startDate);
ElectionListResponse response = adminDao.getElections('>' );
Election firstElection = response.getFirst() // Or whatever method(s) get you the first one
Assert.assertEquals("2018-06-05 00:00", firstElection.getStartDate());
```

These tests confirm that the `Election` has its `startDate` mapped properly from the result set, but they don't care at all how `AdminDaoImpl` does it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're mocking DateFormat then why you're creating SimpleDateFormat object. You should provide **when()** and **thenReturn()** wherever you're using SimpleDateFormat object. All the dependencies should be mocked, no actual object creation would be there.

No database interaction would be there while unit testing of DAO, you can easily mock the db layer.

```
when(df.format("your_date").thenReturn(some_value);
```

Comment: Im getting this now: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: What is value rs.getDate("start date").

Comment: You should mock executeQuery method.